# Regular Expressions in Javascript erasing spaces

Tags: character-replacement

JAVASCRIPT REGULAR EXPRESSIONS

This code searches for single quotation marks and replaces them with double quotation marks.  It will not replace a single quotation mark that is part of a word (i.e. don't)

```
function testRegExp(str)
{
    var matchedStr = str.replace(/\W'|'\W/gi, '"');
    return matchedStr;
}
console.log(testRegExp("I'm in a 'blue house with a cat' and I don't care!"))
```

RESULT --->I'm in a"blue house with a cat"and I don't care!

Notice there are no spaces were the double quotation marks replace the single quotation marks.  Why did the space disappear before and after this quotation?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\W'|'\W/gi
```

You are replacing any non-word character followed by a single quote (`\W'`) or (`|`) any single quote followed by a non-word character (`'\W`) with a double quote without any spaces.

Spaces count as non-word characters, so you are basically replacing the space and single quote with a double quote without spacing.

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
function testRegExp(str)
{
    var matchedStr = str.replace(/\W'/g, ' "').replace(/'\W/g, '" ');
    return matchedStr;
}

console.log(testRegExp("I'm in a 'blue house with a cat' and I don't care!"))
```

Comment: I left out the i modifier because it is unnecessary for this particular argument .

Comment: Fantastic!  I forgot the space was counted as a non-word character, that was getting irritating...